# Sending email from CiviCRM via Gmail SMTP - two-factor authentication

Tags: email, smtp

Problem: how to use Gmail SMTP service from CiviCRM ("System Settings -> Outbound Email") when the Gmail account is set up for two-factor authentication.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The solution is [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26736062/sending-email-fails-when-two-factor-authentication-is-on-for-gmail).
Generate a sixteen-digit token and use the token instead of your Gmail password. So the SMTP settings will be:
SMTP server - smtp.gmail.com
SMTP port - 587
Authentication - Yes
SMTP username - Gmail account username
SMTP password - 16-digit token (not your Gmail password)